# why geom_density makes an artificial peak at the beginning of the plot which is not seen in base plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code produces two density plots, first using the R base graphics and the second using ggplot2. The second plot has an artificial peak at the beginning of the curve which is not present in the first plot. The peak at the start is always present when start of the x-axis limit is set to more than zero. Why ggplot makes this peak and how to avoid it?

I can't post images due to lack of reputation points. PLease, try it yourself. This code  should work as it is.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(101)
xval<-rlnorm(n=10000)
xdf<-data.frame(xval)

plot(density(xdf$xval), xlim=c(1, 10))
ggplot(data=xdf, aes(x=xval))+geom_density()+xlim(1, 10)
```

Is this a bug in ggplot2?

Comment: Try with `ggplot(data=xdf, aes(x=xval)) + geom_density() + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 10))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `xlim()` for `coord_cartesian()`, it works:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(101)
xval <- rlnorm(n=10000)
xdf <- data.frame(xval)

par(xaxs = "i") # change the style to fix exact x limits to (1, 10)
plot(density(xdf$xval), xlim = c(1, 10))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = xdf, aes(x = xval)) + 
  stat_density(geom = "line") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2,4,6,8,10)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the trick. It worked for me. However, does somebody know if this is a feature that is common in some kind of analysis? or is it something that ggplot does for no reason? I am new to ggplot and hence scared of such unwanted services as it may cause trouble if I am presenting these results in a meeting and someone point this out to me before I know what's happening?